# Bootstrap Vue Table with custom Buttons Add & Delete

Tags: vue.js, html-table, bootstrap-4, datatables

I want to create a dynamic bootstrap table that looks something like this:
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcome.html

Currently I am using this code to display my data from an array in the bootstrap table:

`<b-table striped hover :items="shotlist_tab.shots"></b-table>`

But I also want to add custom buttons on the side for each row (edit / delete).

Is there a way to customize the columns of a "b-table"? I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use slots. You can read [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#custom-data-rendering) about that.

If you provide some more code I can help you with that.

Also, one good [example](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#complete-example) of using slots and collapse data inside the row.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add fields to my data and then I could use the slots